# Можно ли с  помощью Intent открыть галерею?

Tags: android-sdk, android

Можно ли с  помощью Intent открыть галерею?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вопрос задан излишне широко. Как вариант можно так:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

intent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(intent, SOME_CODE);
```

Comment: Просто открыть галерею, где хранятся фотографии и картинки, без всяких дальнейших действий над выбранной картинкой. Про SOME_CODE полазал на сайтах, не встречал.  Спасибо, буду разбираться дальше.

Comment: SOME_CODE - это просто некое число, которое будет возвращаться из Activity, когда пользователь выберет картинку в галерее.

Answer (score 3):

Создайте произвольную функцию например

```
public void openfile(View v) throws
Exception  {
     Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
     intent.setType("image/*");
     startActivityForResult(intent, OPEN_FILE); 
}
```

`OPEN_FILE` - это константа её можно объявить глобально до

```
@Override
public void onCreate....

private static final int OPEN_FILE = 300;
```

Затем в методе `onActivityResult`:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int
requestCode, int resultCode, Intent
data) {

super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    if(requestCode == OPEN_FILE){ 
        //выбрали рисунок из галерееи
        Uri ChossefileUri = data.getData(); 
        if(ChossefileUri !=null){ 
            fileUri = ChossefileUri;
            if(fileUri != null) 
            {
               //тут уже работейте с fileUri вашего файла
            }
        }
     } 
 }
```

Comment: @Александр Туткевич, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.